# What is the difference between two sequence_loss functions in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are two ***sequence_loss*** functions one in the  **tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss** and other one in the 
**tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss**. What is the difference ?

Comment: A few bugs was found in the old seq2seq so they moved it to legacy. *Just use the new one*

Comment: So there's is no any structural difference ?